# Many temporary UnknownHost errors when running `bundle install` on linux mint with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems, rvm

I am running RVM on Linux Mint 17 and am hitting a recurring, random, temporary error when I `bundle install`:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: no such name (https://rubygems.org/gems/some_gem)
```

This error happens randomly. If I run `bundle install` again, it might succeed for the previous failure but then hit the error for a different gem farther down the Gemfile.

I am able to successfully install gems, but only after re-running the command many time.

Comment: Having similar issue today in the same environment, Linux Mint 17, RVM. Lot of 'Gem::RemoteFetcher::UnknownHostError: timed out' errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should update your rubygems, if you are not using last version
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/762

It also can be an issue with your DNS setup, check

```
nslookup rubygems.org
```

If it fails - it can be problem with DNS server that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

update rubygem: 
`gem update --system`

Comment: While this short hint might consitute an answer to the original question, without any explanation of the why and how this is an answer it will be difficult for OP and other users to benefit from it.